# gxt grid not display data but the data been loaded

Tags: grid, gxt

There is a basic grid and load data from database using rpc.But the data content is not display in grid cell,but the data number is showing,because i used RowNumberer in the grid.

I have used "System.out.println()" to test load data from database,that is correct,and use alertmessagebox to test the data transmited to clientside with rpc ,that is correct too.

Then from chromedev tools,i saw the information in console that is "Getter was called on ValueProvider, but no getter exists",i do not know why,because i use the same method to load data in other grids which is correct.

So looking for someone's help,thanks!

[error information in chromedev tools console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9ZXE.jpg)
[in grid only 2 line but no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAagg.jpg)

Comment: Without code it is hard to help.

Comment: i made a mistake,rewrite the properties that is fine,thanks

Comment: Could you provide a test case, so I can see how you've got it wired? If you need something to start with to make it easier you can find a grid example in my list of gists that could be used. https://gist.github.com/branflake2267

Comment: I rewrite the properties interface,that it works fine,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while i was trying fetch the date from the Dto class.

In my case i was able to resolve it by correcting the Typo in the method name.

Usually with PropertyAccess interface the ValueProvider customerNo(); 
looks for the getCustomerNo() with CAPITAL 'C' getter method in the dto class.

This error pops-up during the DevMode compilation time and look for the same if it occurs.

Hope this will help .